# Why do I get an undefined Foundation variable error in this SASS file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I have a Rails 4 app, using the foundation-rails v5.2.1.0 gem, and one custom SCSS file for my application layout. When I use a variable from the `foundation_and_overrides.scss` file, I get the following error:

```
Undefined variable: "$header-font-family"
```

I've included relevant code below. I can post more if needed. Anyone know what's going on here?

From `application.css`:

```
*
 *= require foundation_and_overrides
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

From `foundation_and_overrides.scss`:

```
// We use these to control header font styles
$header-font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
$header-font-weight: 400;
// $header-font-style: normal;
```

From `custom.css.scss`:

```
$include-html-global-classes: false;
@import "foundation/components/global";
. 
. 
. 
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: $header-font-family;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error because `foundation_and_overrides.scss`  is executing after  `custom.css.scss`. Best way to do this is to define your variables in a partial and import it in your main stylesheet after foundation.

First change the file name from

`foundation_and_overrides.scss`  to `_foundation_and_overrides.scss`

and then import it in  `custom.css.scss` file after foundation with

```
@import 'foundation_and_overrides';
```

## Update

Rename your  `application.css`  to  `application.css.scss`  and  `custom.css.scss`  to  `custom.scss`

In your  `application.css.scss`  remove  `*= require_tree .`

And then import your main stylesheet with

```
@import 'custom'
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Great! Thank you. One question, will this end up increasing the total weight of the CSS files sent to the clent? Meaning: will I be sending duplicate files now?

Comment: @blundin You should remove *= require foundation_and_overrides from your application.scss file and import your overrides in custom.scss  after importing foundation. If you view the source of the page then you will see only application.css file with the content of your import without any duplication.

Comment: If you work with subfolders in assets/stylesheets and you get the 
`Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: global.` error, there is a workaround https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3855 (namely, `config.sass.load_paths += [
  "#{Gem.loaded_specs['foundation-rails'].full_gem_path}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/components",
  "#{Gem.loaded_specs['foundation-rails'].full_gem_path}/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/"
]`)

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to add the line

```
@import "custom";
```

to your file `foundation_and_overrides.scss` *before* the line

```
@import "foundation";
```

There's no need to remove `*= require_tree .` from `application.css.scss` as stated in the accepted answer. There's also no need to add `require foundation_and_overrides` to `application.css` if you leave `require_tree .` in there.

Comment: How does this provide anything over the existing answer?

Comment: It allows you to keep your application.css.scss clean and working (``require tree .`` is needed for pulling in the css files and shouldn't be removed).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails Docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass >@import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. When using Sprockets >directives, Sass files exist within their own scope, making variables or >mixins only available within the document they were defined in.

So in this case the order of the directives (the lines in application.css that start with *=) doesn't matter because each of those files lives in its own scope and you can't access their variables from another scss file. That's why you want to either @import foundation_and_overrides and then custom, or @import your custom stylesheet *into* foundation_and_overrides.